# How use presentViewController in IOS static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I am building `iOS` static library for sending **SMS** in `xcode`, but when i call `presentViewController()` in the code it is showing following error

```
"No visible @interface for 'SMSLibrary' declares 'presentViewController'
```

Below is my `SMSLibrary.m` code

```
- (void)showSMS:(NSString*)file {

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
NSArray *recipents = @[@"12345678", @"72345524"];
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Msg String", file];

MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setRecipients:recipents];
[messageController setBody:message];
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
//Error in above line "No visible @interface for 'SMSLibrary' declares 'presentViewController' 
}
```

It is my library project, for normal `xcode` application above code is working fine, but when i use above code in the library it is showing above mentioned error.

Comment: What is SMSLibrary's superclass?

Comment: This would have been possible only when SMSLibrary were the subclass of a UIViewController. You will need to maintain a reference to the UIViewController which will create an object of SMSLibrary within this class.